# Custom order categories in admin dashboard

Tags: categories, admin, dashboard, order

everyone, is there way to order categories in add/edit post in admin dashboard. The problem is my order must be custom, not by Name or ID. For example:

- Rumors (id 5)
- News (id 1)
- Features (id 7)
- etc.

  The ideal solution will be to order categories by description. That way in category description field I will put number or letter and categories will order right.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `get_terms_args` hook and modify the `orderby` argument, like so:

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'my_sort_terms', 10, 2 );
function my_sort_terms( $args, $taxonomies ) {

    $args['orderby'] = 'description';

    return $args;
}
```

Possible values for this argument are listed in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms).

Comment: Thank you for the fast comment. With your code and little edits, now it check the description of the categories and order them like I want.